# my sql fetch array and json

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have a function; if the function is working 
`url = "ambildata.php?akhir=0";` is executed and then do

```
$query = "SELECT id_hijau, judul, deskripsi, jenis, x, y FROM hijau ORDER BY id_hijau DESC LIMIT 1";
```

after that

```
$data = mysql_query($query);

$json = '{"wilayah": {';
$json .= '"petak":[ ';
while($x = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
    $json .= '{';
    $json .= '"id":"'.$x["id_hijau"].'",
        "judul":"'.htmlspecialchars($x["judul"]).'",
        "deskripsi":"'.htmlspecialchars($x["deskripsi"]).'",
        "x":"'.$x["x"].'",
        "y":"'.$x["y"].'",
        "jenis":"'.$x["jenis"].'"

    },';
}
$json = substr($json,0,strlen($json)-1);
$json .= ']';

$json .= '}}';

echo $json;
```

but i have an error

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ta\web\ambildata.php on line 13
{"wilayah": {"petak":[]}}

please help me solve my problem...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query produced an error in stead of results. As noted in [the documentation for mysql_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), it will return BOOL false if there is an error. Use [mysql_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to see what's going on.

***EDIT***:
What your error means is that you are passing in either TRUE of FALSE to mysql_fetch_array, which indicates that your `$data` is either TRUE of FALSE, and since `$data = mysql_query($query);`, that means mysql_query is returning TRUE or FALSE, and the only time it does that is when there is an error executing the query; it returns false. This means that the *real* issue is not with mysql_fetch_array, but with your query or elsewhere at the DB level.

Comment: this is the error 

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ta\web\ambildata.php on line 13
{"wilayah": {"petak":[]}}

Comment: Edited answer, that message just indicates that there is a problem executing the query.